# SQL Server Management Studio - Always on Top

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.50.1617.0. Recently it seems to have taken an "always on top" mode, like that of Task Manager. It's not a massive issue but can be annoying after years of alt+tab to change what i'm working on. Anybody got any ideas how to turn it off?

Comment: you may want to try this exchange dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cheers James, have just posted it there too.

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me.
Restarting seems to have corrected it for now.